# jplayer and odd jquery behavior

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jplayer

I'm trying to modify all jplayer titles using the wordpress plugin version.

when adding things
the title is stored in a span called .T_mp3j

```
<span class="T_mp3j" id="T_mp3j_0">1. Blow-Out-Original-Mix3.mp3</span>
```

when trying to update this in the .ready handler it only appends the value, not replace it.

say

```
 $('.T_mp3j').html("PLAY SNIPPET");
```

(or  $('.T_mp3j').text("PLAY SNIPPET") );

results in

```
<span class="T_mp3j" id="T_mp3j_0">
"PLAY SNIPPET"
"1. Blow-Out-Original-Mix3.mp3"
</span>
```

however, running the same  from the consoles (in chrome or firefox) makes the text replace and not append.

```
<span class="T_mp3j" id="T_mp3j_0">PLAY SNIPPET</span>
```

also 
    $('.T_mp3j').empty();
does nothing in .ready but empties in the console.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the wordpress plugin add the information with jQuery itself, and your function is run before they add the text, or?

The code works fine if i test it, so there is something interfering with it in your site.

Your working script:
http://jsfiddle.net/DdGNT/